# Deleting images but can't avoid deleting command button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not a regular user of vba, so when I started doing this code I was totally blank. I already deleted all the images on the worksheet, including command buttons and a logo I didn't meant to delete.

This is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim Pic As Object

Range("D20:D3000").ClearContents

For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
Pic.Delete
Next Pic


End Sub
```

As you can see I need it to delete the images on the D column, but it deletes the images of the whole sheet.
I can't find a way to exclude command buttons (I'm using 2 on that sheet) of the deleting instruccion. Would some of you please, please, please help me? I'm a mess right now.

Answer (score 1):

> I need it to delete the images on the D column, but it deletes the images of the whole sheet.

You are iterating all pictures on the sheet, and never verify *where on the sheet* the picture is before you invoke its `Delete` method.

Interestingly, if you have one picture and one ActiveX command button on `Sheet1`, then `Sheet1.Pictures.Count` returns, unexpectedly, `2` - that's why the loop is also deleting command buttons.

I'd suggest iterating the `Shapes` collection instead: a `Shape` object has an interface that makes it much easier to tell a picture apart from an ActiveX button, ...and to know where on the sheet it's at.

Using `Shape.Type` we can know if we're looking at a `msoPicture`, and with `Shape.TopLeftCell` we can get a `Range` object representing the top-left cell the picture is located at; if the `Column` of that `Range` is `4`, then we're looking at a shape whose upper-left corner is located in column D. Thus:

```
Dim currentShape As Shape
For Each currentShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If currentShape.Type = msoPicture And currentShape.TopLeftCell.Column = 4 Then
        currentShape.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Note how declaring an explicit type that isn't `Object` for our loop variable, we get compile-time validation, and autocomplete/intellisense for every single one of these member calls, whereas calls made against `Object` are all late-bound (i.e. compiles perfectly fine with typos, even if you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module) and will only blow up at run-time if anything is wrong (e.g. error 438 if you try to invoke a member that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

The following compares the picture's range with your range and deletes it if they intersect:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim objPicture As Object
    Dim objPictureRange As Object
    Dim objRange As Object

    Set objRange = Range("D20:D3000")
    objRange.ClearContents

    For Each objPicture In ActiveSheet.Pictures

        ' Get Picture's range
        Set objPictureRange = Range(objPicture.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & objPicture.BottomRightCell.Address)

        ' Check if Picture is in Range
        If Not Intersect(objRange, objPictureRange) Is Nothing Then
            ' Delete picture
            objPicture.Delete
        End If

    Next Pic

End Sub
```